# How to finesse ctrl-f binding from atom package vim-mode-plus

Tags: atom-editor

If I comment out line 113 from `~/.atom/packages/vim-mode-plus/keymaps/vim-mode-plus.cson` will it have the effect of restoring the original meaning of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> by unmasking it from the vim-mode-plus binding?

Like this:

```
--- /old/vim-mode-plus/keymaps/vim-mode-plus.cson   2017-07-23         22:16:37.820417233 -0400
+++ /new/vim-mode-plus/keymaps/vim-mode-plus.cson   2017-07-23 22:25:03.781091855 -0400
@@ -110,7 +110,7 @@
   'ctrl-u': 'vim-mode-plus:scroll-half-screen-up'
   'ctrl-b': 'vim-mode-plus:scroll-full-screen-up'
   'ctrl-d': 'vim-mode-plus:scroll-half-screen-down'
-  'ctrl-f': 'vim-mode-plus:scroll-full-screen-down'
+  ## 'ctrl-f': 'vim-mode-plus:scroll-full-screen-down'
   'ctrl-e': 'vim-mode-plus:scroll-down'
   'ctrl-y': 'vim-mode-plus:scroll-up'
```

NB: vim-mode-plus is the only package that has been added to my original Atom installation on Linux.

Everything about this package is great, but I don't need a command to scroll down one window, and I DO need a 'search this buffer' command that uses the find/replace options mini-window.

Answer (score 1):

I assume by the "original meaning" that you mean to show the find panel. Yes, that is possible.

However, first I will say that you should not comment things out of the package files the way you have done. The next time that package is upgraded, your changes will be lost. So step 1 is to undo the change you have made in the package file.

The place to override keymaps is in your config directory, in the file `keymap.cson`. On Linux this would be found in `~/.atom/keymap.cson`. This file is intentionally loaded after packages are loaded, so that you can use it to override package keymaps.

To add this override, you want something like this:

```coffeescript
'atom-text-editor':
    'ctrl-f': 'find-and-replace:show'
```

Another option is to use it as a toggle. By default the keybinding will always show the panel (so you can only open it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F</kbd>, and must close with <kbd>Esc</kbd>). I prefer to open and close with the same key, and there is also a command for that. I have a similar map for the Project Find panel.

```coffeescript
'atom-text-editor':
    'ctrl-f': 'find-and-replace:toggle'
    'shift-ctrl-f': 'project-find:toggle'
```